# I have installed iOS6 simulator in xcode5, but I can't run app on iOS6 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

There is no option on the left corner of  Xcode to select to run on iOS6 or iOS7 simulator. While there should be.  The storyboard builds for iOS6.1 and later. How could I run my app on iOS6 simulator?

Comment: Is this a project you created with Xcode 5?

Comment: Yes. I create it by xocde5

Comment: Then vikingosegundo answer is probably what you need to do. By default xcode creates projects with the deployment target set to the latest OS. You'll need to change the value to deploy to earlier OSes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option on the top left corner to select which simulator you want:

[image]

You also have to select the right Architecture to be able to change the Deployment Targeet:

[image]

To further prove that you have to remove the 64 bits:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: while the problem is that I can't find the option

Comment: @vikingosegundo really? I couldn't change to 6.1 with the other one selected. This is what I get: "Applications targeting the ARM64 architecture are not currently compatible with iOS versions prior to 7.0.  To deploy an application to iOS releases prior to iOS 7, adjust the architecture setting to remove the ARM64 option."

Comment: I have no problems with `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)`

Comment: @vikingosegundo well... I'm not really sure what's going on but I'm not making this up. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: maybe the target family. You are using iPad, I am using iPhone.

Comment: I remove the 64bit and set the deployment target to 6.1.  But the app still run in the iOS 7 simulator.

Comment: set the deployment target to 6.1 doesn't work. But set the target to 6.0 works! Thanks a lot! Architecture setting really helps!

Answer (score 3):

You might need to install additional iOS simulator.
To install additional tools and software go to:

**xcode preference -> downloads**.

Answer (score 0):

you must change your deployment target to 6.1. if you cannot select that you might need to install additional packets from the settings of xcode.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: install what packet? I have installed ios6 simulator.

Comment: did you try to select 6.1 in the deployment target setting?

Answer (score 0):

@LuisCien's answer is correct, though your VALID_ARCHS may need to be edited as well. The key point there being that ARCHS and VALID_ARCHS cannot contain arm64. As @LuisCien and others have pointed out, the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET must be 6.1 or earlier.

Comment: this is not true. I can compile for both (6.1 & 7) with `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)`